# Xcode Don't recognize Object anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, nsobject

I have an object named friend (I know, first letter should be uppercase). I use this class in many other classes and view controller.

All of a sudden, without changing ANY CODE, every custom object I have, stopped recognize each other. I always get the error Unknown type name "friend".

I already tried to clear the project and restart the mac.
WTF is wrong with this Xcode? All of a sudden my whole project stops working.

Here is my class currentUser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "friend.h"

@interface currentUser : NSObject<NSCoding>
{
    BOOL fromfacebook;
    @private
    NSMutableArray *upLoadStack;

}

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *token;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong)UIImage *userImg;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *facebookID;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *userPSW;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *userID;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *friendsList;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *groups;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSData *audioMessage;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *mimosToDownload;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *mimosDownloaded;
@property (nonatomic,strong)friend *friendToSend; //Here is where a I get the error of unknown type name


@end
```

this is the friend.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "currentUser.h"
#import "Imager.h"

@interface friend : NSObject<NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *userID;
@property (nonatomic,strong)UIImage *userImg;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableData *buffer;

@property(nonatomic)BOOL flagDownloaded;
-(UIImage*)downloadImageBlocked;
-(id)init;
-(UIImage*)getFriendImg;
-(UIImage*)userImg;
-(NSString*)getUserID;
-(NSString*)getUserName;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;
-(bool)isNil;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix the stuff that you know is wrong first...

change

```
@interface currentUser : NSObject<NSCoding>
{
    BOOL fromfacebook;
    @private
    NSMutableArray *upLoadStack;

}
```

to

```
@interface User : NSObject<NSCoding>
{
    BOOL fromfacebook;
    @private
    NSMutableArray *upLoadStack;

}
```

you don't need to know if the user is current or not for the user to have properties of a user, think of them as actually representing objects.

change:

```
@interface friend : NSObject<NSCoding>
```

to

```
@interface Friend : NSObject<NSCoding>
```

you know it is wrong, fix it now before you have to fix it in 1000 places instead of 100 places.

Convention is very important in Objective-C.

also don't import everything into your header if you don't need to...

```
@class Friend; //forward class declaration

@interface currentUser : NSObject<NSCoding>
...
@property (nonatomic,strong)Friend *friendToSend; //Here is where a I get the error of unknown type name
```

and as for your ivar's in `currentUser` you don't need those in the interface (they can go in a block after the @implimentation line), unless you need them for backwards compatibility...

Comment: It worked! Thanks, the problem is this is an old project, when I started to program in Objective-c, I will pay more attention to these details.